# output suddenly separate int with space

Tags: c, arrays, output

```
int sales[ 1 ];
do
{
    scanf_s( "%d", sales, 1 ); 

    printf( "\n%d\n", sales[ 0 ] );

    printf( "\nyou got weekly income of $ %d\n\n", commision( sales[ 0 ] ) );

} while ( sales[0] >-1 );
```

I want to ask, why every time i input int with space (example 123 456), the output is sales[0]=123 then suddenly it automatically assign 456 to sales[0],
can you guys explain it why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is that it reads a signed number from the standard input. (`%d` does read until the whitespace but ignores the whitespace itself.) It then writes that number (the first number would be `123`) to your `sales` array at index `0`. Then you're writing the return value of your `commision(...)` function to standard output.

> then suddenly it automatically assign 456 to sales[0]

If by that you mean that at the end of the program's execution `sales[0]` contains `456` instead of `123` it is because the whole procedure I described above is done as long as your `do while` loop runs. And if sales[0] is greater than `-1` which is the case for `sales[0]` being `123` after the first procedure it will run again and read `456` from the standard input and write that to the `sales` array.

Some more examples for `scanf_s("%d", int_pointer, 1)` reading input from `stdin`:

- Input `42 43ab 44` would be read in 3 different `scanf_s` as `42`, `43` and `44`.
- Input `42  a` would be read in 2 different `scanf_s` as `42` and `0`.
- Input `42 a a43 44` would be read in 4 different `scanf_s` as `42`, `0`, `0` and `44`.

Comment: i see....but why the rule doesnt apply for char type(example i input ab[white space]d the output only sales="ab" and the string after [white space] deleted?

and one more thing i still confused, where did the the compiler store the 456?because first he assign 123 to sales[0] and there is no variable left for storing 456....after the first loop done, it executes the 2nd loop (scanf statement), why the scanf suddenly get the 456?where did come from? correct me if i'm worng

Comment: What do you mean by "apply for char type"? If your variable is of type `char` (like `char sales[1]`) and you're doing `scanf_s("%d", sales, 1)` then `scanf_s` will still interpret the input as a an signed integer. That means as soon as you send e.g. a whitespace or line break the input will be parsed and all characters of the input forming a valid signed int will be "put into" the variable (here `sales`) - all trailing ones will be ignored (input `42ab` = `42`. If (like in my above example) `sales` is of type `char`, the read integer will be an 8 bit one instead of 32 (most `int`s) or 64 bits.

Comment: The compiler does nothing here. It's all happening at run time of the program. In the second execution of the `do while` `scanf_s` just *replaces* the value in `sales[0]` - so `123` gets replaced by `456`.

Comment: example i have char x[5], and then i do scanf_s("%s", x,5),when i input ab[space]c,it only print ab (in this case i do printf(" %s ", x ));and the next loop didnt print c, but for my first case, when i have a variable of int( sales [1] ),when i input 123[space]456, it prints out 123 and for the next loop it prints 456, so it means the rule apply for int type but it doesnt apply for char type, can you explain why?

Comment: If you have `char x[5]` and read a string from `stdin` with format string containing `%s` you are also reading chars until a whitespace occurs. The reason why it doesn't execute a second loop might be the actual while condition being evaluated as false. You should look into the [docs of `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) which btw is just a Windows version of [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or get more information from C guides explaining the format string stuff. If this has helped you you can also mark my answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because scanf is picky and it wants the exact input of one number. To it the whitespace signals the end of the desired input format.

123[whitespace] -> 123 is assigned, stuff happens, loops again.

456[whitespace] -> 456 is assigned, stuff happens, loops again.

Answer (score 0):

```
int commission(int i) {
    return 42*i;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int sales[ 1 ];
    do
    {
        scanf_s( "%d", sales, 1 );

        printf( "\n%d\n", sales[ 0 ] );

        printf( "\nyou got weekly income of $ %d\n\n", commission( sales[ 0 ] ) );
        sales[0] = -1; // Won't jump to the next value
    } while ( sales[0] >-1 ); // But then what's the point of the loop?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Or are you trying to ask a separate question here, Philip?